# phpMyAdmin Cron to Delete Temporary Files

Tags: unix, cron, phpmyadmin

I have a folder on my hosting which I periodically upload something to - `/public_html/uploads` - and I'd like to set up a cronjob through phpMyAdmin to empty it out on a regular basis.

The current cron I have in pMA is

`find /public_html/uploads -maxdepth 1 -ctime 1 -exec rm -f {} \;`

http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/668/1274390599451.png

(Ignore the fact that it's running every minute for now, it's so I can test it :) )

I know very little about what this command is actually doing, but it looks like "not very much". Can anyone help me fix it? :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The command is looking for files in the directory that where somehow modified in the last day and deletes them.

If you just want to delete everything in the directory you could just use a:

`rm -f /public_html/uploads/*`

As the cron job command